# Plot a summation

Tags: plotting, summation

How can I plot

```
 f = Sum[(4 Sqrt[6])/(n^2 π^2) Sin[(n π)/2], {n, 1, 20}]
```

I need to plot the sum of the first 20 terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of values for n and the Sum using Table. Then ListPlot can plot it.

```
tab = Table[{n1, 
   Sum[(4 Sqrt[6])/(n^2 π^2) Sin[(n*π)/2], {n, 1, n1}]}, {n1, 
   1, 20}];

ListPlot[tab]
```

Please let me know if this is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you tell me what is wrong when :-

Comment: f = Sum[(4 Sqrt[6])/(n^2 \[Pi]^2) Sin[(n*\[Pi])/2], {n, 1, 20}]
    Plot[Table[f, {n, 1, 20}], PlotRange -> All]

Comment: 1. You have [Pi] which is wrong Syntax. You should have (Pi). 2. The Sum is just a number. You cannot plot a number. You have to plot the Sum value as n changes. That is why I suggested Table